# Merge Lists in PHP

Tags: php

This is an interview question which I faced.
I have two **lists** like [1,2,3] and [a,b,c] .How to get a result **list** as merge each element from both the lists like [1,a,2,b,3,c].Is this an invalid question ?Please don't treat them as arrays!!

Comment: Those are short-noted arrays(at least in php 5.5). You can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Then how do you represent the lists in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: Its not a list but an array. I think you might be misguided by yourself or the interviewer

Comment: I re asked whether its an array,but they where firm with the  list only!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )` [Check PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
or `array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )` [Check PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)